# CREATE PROCEDURE in MySQL: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a mySQL procedure in phpmyadmin and it keeps throwing this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 18

I've tried the code below with and without the delimiter, without avail. Can anyone point to what's wrong with this code?

```
DELIMITER \\
CREATE PROCEDURE ORDERBOOKS(IN store VARCHAR(10), IN title VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    DECLARE order_num VARCHAR(100); 
    DECLARE tod DATE;
    SELECT @ordered_qty := qty FROM customer_sales WHERE customer_sales.store_id = store AND customer_sales.title_id = title;
    SELECT @in_stock := qty FROM store_inventories WHERE store_inventories.stor_id=store AND store_inventories.title_id = title;
    SELECT @threshold := minStock FROM store_inventories WHERE store_inventories.stor_id=store AND store_inventories.title_id = title;
    SET order_num = CONCAT(store, title);
    SET tod = GETDATE();
    IF (@ordered_qty < (@in_stock - @threshold)) THEN UPDATE store_inventories SET qty = (@in_stock - @ordered_qty) WHERE store_inventories.stor_id = store and store_inventories.title_id = title;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO pending_orders(stor_id, ord_num, title_id, qty, date, fulfilled) VALUES(store, order_num, title, (@ordered_qty + @threshold), tod ,1);
        INSERT INTO sales VALUES(store, order_num, tod);
        INSERT INTO salesdetail VALUES(store, order_num, title , (@ordered_qty + @threshold),0);
        UPDATE pending_orders SET fulfilled=0 WHERE pending_orders.stor_id = store AND pending_orders.title_id = title;
        UPDATE store_inventories SET qty = (@threshold + @in_stock) WHERE store_inventories.stor_id = store and store_inventories.title_id= title;
        DELETE FROM pending_orders WHERE pending_orders.stor_id = store AND pending_orders.title_id = title;
END\\

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: missing an end if

Comment: Unrelated tip: assigning user defined `@` variables is safer (and silent) if you use a scalar subquery: `SET @ordered_qty = (SELECT qty FROM customer_sales WHERE customer_sales.store_id = store AND customer_sales.title_id = title);` You might at some point be inclined to rewrite your original statements as `SELECT ... INTO` if you decided to refactor this, and that has (often) [unintended consequences](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35207/11651) of old values sticking around from invocation to invocation by the same connection.  Better to use a safer assignment paradigm, now, fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ORDERBOOKS(IN store VARCHAR(10), IN title VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    DECLARE order_num VARCHAR(100); 
    DECLARE tod DATE;
    SELECT @ordered_qty := qty FROM customer_sales WHERE customer_sales.store_id = store AND customer_sales.title_id = title;
    SELECT @in_stock := qty FROM store_inventories WHERE store_inventories.stor_id=store AND store_inventories.title_id = title;
    SELECT @threshold := minStock FROM store_inventories WHERE store_inventories.stor_id=store AND store_inventories.title_id = title;
    SET order_num = CONCAT(store, title);
    SET tod = GETDATE();
    IF (@ordered_qty < (@in_stock - @threshold)) THEN UPDATE store_inventories SET qty = (@in_stock - @ordered_qty) WHERE store_inventories.stor_id = store and store_inventories.title_id = title;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO pending_orders(stor_id, ord_num, title_id, qty, date, fulfilled) VALUES(store, order_num, title, (@ordered_qty + @threshold), tod ,1);
        INSERT INTO sales VALUES(store, order_num, tod);
        INSERT INTO salesdetail VALUES(store, order_num, title , (@ordered_qty + @threshold),0);
        UPDATE pending_orders SET fulfilled=0 WHERE pending_orders.stor_id = store AND pending_orders.title_id = title;
        UPDATE store_inventories SET qty = (@threshold + @in_stock) WHERE store_inventories.stor_id = store and store_inventories.title_id= title;
        DELETE FROM pending_orders WHERE pending_orders.stor_id = store AND pending_orders.title_id = title;
    END IF
END
```

Comment: `;` is required after `END IF`, and you should probably leave the statement delimiters and delimiter declarations in, for clarity.